# How to prove this is a decreasing sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ratio

I have this sequence: $\{a_n\} = {\frac {1}{n^{1+\frac {1}{n}}}}$
I tried to take the derivative to show the rate of change is negative for some n but the derivative is not very nice to work with. I tried to show $\frac {\{a_{n+1}\}}{\{a_n\}}<1$ but again the ratio didn't clearly show that to me. What other method can I try to clearly show as n increases the sequence decreases?
EDIT: Also is there any property to say that if a sequence is bounded above by a decreasing sequence, then our sequence is also decreasing? Like $\frac {1}{n}$ in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Being bounded above by a decreasing sequence does *not* imply that a sequence is decreasing.

---

Since the logarithm is an increasing function, it is sufficient to show that

$$\ln n^{1 + \frac 1 n}$$

is an increasing function. But this just reduces to studying

$$\left(1 + \frac 1 n\right) \ln n.$$

The derivative of this is

$$\left(1 + \frac 1 n\right) \frac 1 n - \frac{\ln n}{n^2} \approx \frac 1 n > 0$$

once $n$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Is there a fast way to notice that the last line is approximately equal to 1/n for large n? I understand intuitively ln(n) is not going to grow nearly as quickly as n^2 but I was wondering if there was a more formal technique to show it?

Comment: Yes, there is. $\log (1+x) \leq x$ for all $x>0$ so the expression in the last line is at least equal to $(1+{\frac 1 n} )$ ${\frac 1 n}$ - ${\frac {n-1} {n^{2}}}$ $= {\frac 2 {n^{2}}$. For a proof the inequality for logarithm just note that $e^{x} \geq 1+x$ from its series expansion and taking logarithms gives you what you want.

Comment: Or simply that $(1+1/n)/n-(\ln n)/n^2=(n+1-\ln n)/n^2>0$   because $ n+1-\ln n=$ $n+1-\int_1^n(1/x)dx\geq $ $n+1-\int_1^n(1)dx=$ $n+1-(n-1)=2>0 $ for $n\geq 1.$